# How to define a char constant number in C and C++?

Tags: c++

I can define literal numbers in C and C++ with the help of suffix `L`, `U`, `D`, etc like this:

```
34656345L
94375804U
3.141593F
...
```

So in the expression they appear the compiler knows their types. Is the a similar way to define 1-byte literal numbers like `char`? I know I could use `(char)28` for example, but probably there's a suffix I haven't found.

I have had a look at this page http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/constants/ but no char constants mentioned there.

Comment: `constexpr char c = 28;` ? Or https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal ?

Comment: In C, there are no _literal numbers_, but _constants_  In C, the address of a literal can be taken, but not the address of a constant.  Good that the post is no longer tagged C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no suffix for character literals.

In C++, you can use `'`-enclosed literals like `'\x9f'` (in C they are `int`s), but there is no way to specify a decimal character code this way.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a complete source where it is said so that I could take a loot at and read more about suffixes?

Comment: @Fomalhaut Check https://en.cppreference.com (I think there are several separate pages on different kinds of liteals: integers, reals, ...). It's one of the best C++ resources around.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, `char{28}` does what you want. There [is no suffix](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) for `char` (nor for `unsigned char`) literals.

As @JesperJuhl reminds us, you can [create your own suffix](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) for char literals, if you so desire, like so:

```
constexpr char operator "" _c(int i) { return char{i}; }
```

and then you could write `123_c` which would have type `char`. But - I wouldn't recommend it, it'd probably mostly confuse people.

---

PS: You can use character literals such as `'a'` or `'b'` (which would have values 97 and 98 respectively if your compiler uses an ASCII-compatible character set, e.g. UTF-8 or Latin-1). These will have a `char` type, not an `int` type. See discussion [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal).

Comment: You could always [make your own](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal) suffix - if you so desire ;)